# Laptop speakers don't work

Tags: laptop, audio, speakers

My laptop speakers make a sound when I power on the laptop, but in windows it doesn't make
any sound. However, when I plug in any headphone to it, the sound comes out from the headphones.
I tried changing the windows and even reinstalled sound drivers, but nothing works. What should I try next?

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about your configuration, what gear you have and how it's hooked together.

Comment: can you specify the model of your laptop?

Comment: do you plug the headphone in the same jack as the speakers? or do you use different jacks?

Answer (score 0):

Some sound cards have a function or checkmark in their control panel (or the windows control panel) which mutes the speakers (& allowing jacks to operate normally).

Carefully examine the sound settings in Windows 7. There are non-obvious properties pages and right click menus. Perhaps the speaker is setup as a secondary device.